# TypeScript define object where keys will be from Type?

Tags: typescript

How can I define a type for an object where the keys will come from list that I know, in this case `field_1` and `field_2`

```
type FooKey = 'field_1' | 'field_2';
interface FooValue {
  src: string;
  id: number;
}
interface Foo {
  [FooKey]: FooValue;
}

const thing: Foo = {
  field_1: {
    src: 'src 1',
    id: 1,
  },
  field_2: {
    src: 'src 2',
    id: 2,
  },
};
```

Comment: Add every field to the type and make them optional.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

```js
const d: Record<FooKey, FooValue > = {...}
```

Comment: @Evanss did this answer your question?